# Finding Quantity when Profit = 0

Tags: marginal, profits, perfect-competition

[image]
I'm struggling to find the correct answer which is (B). So far what I've done is say that P=MC as we're in a perfectly competitive market. So profit = PQ - TC which gives 0 = (2Q)Q -(VC+4) ? But we don't know VC so I doubt this method works...

Answer (score 2):

Since

$$TC(Q)=VC(Q)+FC$$

we have

$$MC(Q)=TC'(Q)=VC'(Q)$$

To get $VC$, just find the antiderivative of $MC$ which is zero when $Q=0$. (Alternatively, to get $TC$ find the antiderivative of $MC$ which is equal to the fixed cost of $4$ when $Q=0$.)

In this case $MC(Q)=2Q$, and the antiderivatives are given by $Q^2+a$ for some constant $a$. To ensure $0^2+a=0$, we need to set $a=0$. So $VC(Q)=Q^2$, and we are given that $FC=4$. Thus profit is

$$pQ-TC(Q)=pQ-(Q^2+4)$$

For profit maximization $p=MC(Q)=2Q$, so maximized profit is

$$2Q^2-(Q^2+4)=Q^2-4$$

This is zero when $Q=2$.

Comment: Got it, Thank you !

Comment: Well, actually $a = 4$.

Comment: @MatteoBulgarelli No, $a=0$ if we want the antiderivative of the $MC$ function that represents the $VC$ function. On the other hand, $a=4$ if we want the antiderivative of the $MC$ function that represents the $TC$ function.

Comment: I do agree, that's just a matter of notation, and of course your answer is perfectly fine.
 MY point is: you are basically telling OP that integrating the marginal costs, you a function that is composed of two parts: a variable part, that depends on the quantity you produce, and a fixed part, that is a constant. It would be more intuitive, in my view, to tell students "look, the part of this function that depends on  Q are variable costs, the other, constant part are fixed costs", rather then tellimg them "if you want to find the variable cost function, set the constant to 0.